# Valgrind and OpenGL

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, valgrind

I wrote a simple OpenGL application and decided to test it using valgrind. And received the following messages:

```
==14679== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14679== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14679== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14679== Command: ./out/main.o
==14679==
Starting GLFW context, OpenGL 3.3
==14679== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14679==    at 0x4C32EA6: rawmemchr (vg_replace_strmem.c:1402)
==14679==    by 0x63283C1: _IO_str_init_static_internal (strops.c:41)
==14679==    by 0x631BB96: vsscanf (iovsscanf.c:40)
==14679==    by 0x6316306: sscanf (sscanf.c:32)
==14679==    by 0x94B9E4A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==14679==    by 0x94BA182: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==14679==    by 0x94BDBF8: drmGetDevice (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==14679==    by 0x57EE2D6: ??? (in /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==14679==    by 0x57ED694: ??? (in /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==14679==    by 0x57C1988: ??? (in /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==14679==    by 0x57BCF10: glXQueryVersion (in /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0)
==14679==    by 0x50943F9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so.3.2)
==14679==
==14679==
==14679== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14679==     in use at exit: 45,107 bytes in 460 blocks
==14679==   total heap usage: 18,068 allocs, 17,608 frees, 30,350,802 bytes allocated
==14679==
==14679== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14679==    definitely lost: 448 bytes in 1 blocks
==14679==    indirectly lost: 1,773 bytes in 14 blocks
==14679==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14679==    still reachable: 42,886 bytes in 445 blocks
==14679==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14679== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==14679==
==14679== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14679== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==14679== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

With what it can be connected, and whether it is necessary to me to worry?

**EDIT 1:**

My C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "utils/shader_utils.h"

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/vec4.hpp>

// Window dimensions
const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

// Shaders
const char *vertexShader = "src/resources/shaders/vertex_shader.glsl";
const char *fragmentShader = "src/resources/shaders/fragment_shader.glsl";
const char *vertexShaderSource, *fragmentShaderSource;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Starting GLFW context, OpenGL 3.3" << std::endl;
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    glewInit();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(true);

    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    vertexShaderSource = readShader(vertexShader);
    fragmentShaderSource = readShader(fragmentShader);

    GLuint vertexShader = compileShader(vertexShaderSource, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    // Fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = compileShader(fragmentShaderSource, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    // Link shaders
    GLuint shaderProgram = createProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // Check for linking errors
    //getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    static const GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -0.5f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -0.5f,
        0.0f,  1.0f, -0.5f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.6f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.6f,
        1,  0.0f, -0.6f,
    };

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        su::pointer(0, 3, vertexbuffer);

        su::setVec3(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "in_color"), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        su::setVec3(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "in_color"), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, 3);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();

    delete[] vertexShaderSource;
    delete[] fragmentShaderSource;

    return 0;
}
```

Also, when I try get info log (using `glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, size, NULL, buff)`) I've got messages:

```
==16571== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16571==    at 0x4C2EDA9: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:454)
==16571==    by 0x5B22888: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
==16571== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16571==    at 0x6324F29: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1309)
==16571==    by 0x631A0AA: fwrite (iofwrite.c:39)
==16571==    by 0x5B2258D: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
==16571==    by 0x5B22896: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
```

And other similar errors

Compilation:

```
g++ src/main.cpp -o out/main.o `pkg-config --libs glfw3 glew`
```

**EDIT 2:**

How do I get real data about a memory leak in my application? Accept **448** as zero?

**EDIT 3:**

My `readShader` function:

```
char *readShader(const char *path) {
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "rb");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char *result = new char[size + 1];
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(result, 1, size, file);
    fclose(file);
    result[size] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

I will be grateful for help

Comment: How did you compile and link the library? How did you compile and link you program to the library? Also see [The Valgrind Quick Start Guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.prepare) and pay attention to *"Use of -O2 and above is not recommended as Memcheck occasionally reports uninitialised-value errors which don't really exist"*.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I suggest checking for return codes instead of assuming that all functions succeed (for instance the IO functions).

Comment: It strange that the error message links to standard libraries

Comment: I tested it, and all the programs that use OpenGL have the same errors. But in that case, how can I find a leak specifically in my code? Are there any analogues of Valgrind?